# angular2 – using same component as nested components with different inputs multiple times in single parent component

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to use a bootstrap popup component as nested component multiple times on a single page. This popup component takes different values as `@Input()`. The problem is that every popup on the page has the same values as the last popup. So, how can I get multiple instances of the same nested component?

Here is the parent component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-parent',
  templateUrl: 'app/components/parent/parent.component.html',
  directives: [PopupDirective]
})
export class ParentComponent {
    private doSomething() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

This is the html of my parent component:

```
<button class="btn btn-success"
        (click)="popup1.show()">Call Popup 1</button>

<button class="btn btn-success"
        (click)="popup2.show()">Call Popup 2</button>

<my-popup #popup1
          [id]="1"
          [title]="Popup 1"
          [body]="This is my test popup 1"
          (confirmation)="doSomething()"></my-popup>

<my-popup #popup2
          [id]="2"
          [title]="Popup 2"
          [body]="This is my test popup 2"
          (confirmation)="doSomething()"></my-popup>
```

Here is the popup component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-popup',
  templateUrl: 'app/directives/popup/popup.directive.html'
})
export class PopupDirective {

    @Input() id: string;

    @Input() title: string;
    @Input() body: any;

    @Output() confirmation: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

    private triggerPopup: string;

    constructor() {
        this.triggerPopup = "triggerPopup";
    }

    confirm() {
        this.confirmation.emit('Click from nested component');
    }


    show() {
        document.getElementById(this.triggerPopup).click();
    }
}
```

And finally the html code of my popup

```
<a id="{{ triggerPopup }}"
   href="#popup{{ id }}"
   data-toggle="modal"
   [hidden]="true"></a>

<div class="modal fade" id="popup{{ id }}" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4>{{ title }}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div>{{ body }}</div>
                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a  class="bin ban-default"
                    data-dismiss="modal">
                    Close</a>

                <a  class="bin ban-success"
                    data-dismiss="modal"
                    (click)="confirm()">
                    Confirm</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the same id to each element

```
constructor() {
    this.triggerPopup = "triggerPopup";
}
```

and therefore

```
document.getElementById(this.triggerPopup).click();
```

always finds the first one because it searches the whole page and doesn't care about component boundaries.

I'd suggest to use template variables and `@ViewChild()` instead

```
<a #triggerPopup"
```

```
export class PopupDirective {
  @ViewChild('triggerPopup') triggerPopup:ElementRef;

  show() {
    this.triggerPopup.nativeElement.click();
  }
```

Comment: Okay, thats logical. But it does not fix it at all. I recognized that also `href="#popup{{ id }}"` always will be just `#popup`. I could do the same as in your answer above but then how can I trigger the popup through the bootstrap framework? I can't just do `href="#popup{{ id }}"` because the url would be something like `/#popup [Object]`.

Comment: I'd suggest to use a different input property name than `id`. `id` is a property of `Element`.